# React/RTKQuery: Use lazy query is not forcing a refetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, rtk-query

After hours and Hours of research and trying a bunch of stuff like lazy query subscription, I can't figure out why lazyQuery is not re-fetching as I expect

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import Logout from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import LocalPostOfficeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalPostOffice';
import './ProfileButton.css';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {updateUserIDParam, updatePageParam} from '../../../features/Params';
import {useLazyGetPostsQuery} from '../../../services/PostsApi';

export default function ProfileButton() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const UserIDParam = useSelector((state) => state.Params.value.userId);
  const page = useSelector((state) => state.Params.value.page);
  const sort = useSelector((state) => state.Params.value.sort);

  const [triggerGetPostsQuery] = useLazyGetPostsQuery(); // Tried to pass arguments here 
  as well

  const userID = localStorage.getItem('userID');
  const userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const myPostsButtonOnClick = () => {
    dispatch(updateUserIDParam(`id=${userID}`));
    localStorage.setItem("OldPageValue", page);
    dispatch(updatePageParam(1))
    triggerGetPostsQuery({page, sort, UserIDParam}, {preferCacheValue: false}) // Want 
    re-fetch here
  }
   const showAllPostsButtonOnClick = () => {
    dispatch(updateUserIDParam(""))
    dispatch(updatePageParam(Number(localStorage.getItem("OldPageValue"))))
    triggerGetPostsQuery({page, sort, UserIDParam}, {preferCacheValue: false}) // Want 
    re-fetch here
    localStorage.removeItem("OldPageValue")
  }
```

I cannot use tags or other options here as this component is not a child component of my HomePage or something. I have tried to use lazyQuery without any arguments as well. But it's always using my cached value. I don't wanna remove caching completely as well. Only want these button clicks to force a refetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preferCacheValue` is acutally the second argument, not an option on it.

So you would have to call

```
triggerGetPostsQuery({page, sort, UserIDParam}, false)
```

Since `{preferCacheValue: false}` is a truthy value in JavaScript, you are essentially calling it with

```
triggerGetPostsQuery({page, sort, UserIDParam}, somethingTruthy)
```

which does the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Tysm!! I couldn't find the syntax so clearly like this anywhere. Plus "{preferCacheValue: false} is a truthy value" is something next level. One more thing is when "myPostsButtonOnClick" runs when userIDParam or page gets updated, rtk query is automatically calling my useGetPostQuery from HomePage as one of the parameters changes. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Well, in JavaScript everything that's not `false`, `undefined`, `null` or `0` is "truthy", so a check like `if (value)` will be true. I can really recommend getting into TypeScript, that will catch stuff like this.
As for the other part: if you put a new argument into the query hook, it will make a new request. You'd have to see that you keep that argument stable.